# Operator can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-change-notifier

I'm trying to add shopping functions to my app.  I'm attempting to use ChangeNotifier to add a cart item counter and I am getting the error message 'error: The operator '-' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  I'm new to coding so I have been unable to figure out a solution even after researching on SO.  Thanks in advance for any help provided.

```
class EcommerceApp {

  static late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  static String collectionUser = "users";
  static String collectionOrders = "orders";
  static String userCartList = 'userCart';
  static String subCollectionAddress = 'userAddress';

class CartItemCounter extends ChangeNotifier {
  final int _counter = EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
      .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList)
      ?.length - 1;

  int get count => _counter;
}

    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `getStringList()` has a chance of being `null`. Dart's Null-safety doesn't allow this. You can use the `??` operator to ensure another value in case of it being `null`. I think this might work:

```
class CartItemCounter extends ChangeNotifier {
  final int _counter = (EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
      .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList)
      .length ?? 0) - 1;

  int get count => _counter;
}
```

Comment: It is not `SharedPreferences` that is a nullable type but rather the return value of `getStringList` is `List<String>?` (https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/getStringList.html). You must use `?.length` here rather than `.length` but I think otherwise this answer is correct.

Comment: @chralle if you can edit your answer to reflect comment by mmcdon20 I will mark your answer as accepted as the code has definitely resolved my problem.  Thank you.